# profiler in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, profiling, rubymine

I creating heavy script which analize and store the data and I'm really need to know which lines of my code consuming most of the time.
Is Rubymine have profiler features or maybe it possible to add profiler to it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for it also, but without success. If you find something, please let me know.

Meanwhile... In Ruby itself there are two modules which could help you

**Benchmark** – http://apidock.com/ruby/Benchmark

You do something like this

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 50000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("for:")   { for i in 1..n; a = "1"; end }
  x.report("times:") { n.times do   ; a = "1"; end }
  x.report("upto:")  { 1.upto(n) do ; a = "1"; end }
end
```

and it will give you nice table of profiling results

```
             user     system      total        real
for:     1.050000   0.000000   1.050000 (  0.503462)
times:   1.533333   0.016667   1.550000 (  0.735473)
upto:    1.500000   0.016667   1.516667 (  0.711239)
```

**Profiler__** – http://apidock.com/ruby/Profiler__

Easiest way to use this module is just `require 'profile'` and after your script finish it blow out data about each call.

Check this example http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/profile.htm

Answer (score 1):

Since the 2019.1 version, RubyMine supports profiling using RbSpy. To profile a script:

1. (Optional) Configure the profiler settings on the **Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Ruby Profiler** page.
2. Right-click the script in the editor or Project view, and **select Run 'script name' with 'RbSpy profiler'**.
3. Analyze results in the **Profiler** tool window. The **Flame Chart** tab shows you the state of the call stack at any moment of time. Each frame represents a method/block in the stack (a stack frame). On the Y-axis, there is a stack depth going from bottom up. The X-axis shows the stack sorted from the most time-consuming methods/blocks to the least consuming ones.

You can learn more from the [Profile applications](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/cpu-profiler.html) help topic.